# Text file to comma delimited file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a text file that needs to be converted to a comma delimited file. I have imported my text file into excel and then have chosen the Fixed width and according to this I have separated my columns but it seems not to be successful in the approach I took. Instead, I get the results divided into columns. Is there a way this can be approached so my sample can look like my Result?

What I got, as a result, was `999999 20170826 10:0000 94862546 10420011 43867426 but all I did was set the width in excel. How can my sample look like my given result?`

```
Sample: (This is my file currently) 
9999992017082610:0000948625561042001143867425 

Result : 
Sample CSV record of the fixed length record from above
0094862,999999,08/26/2017,10:00,7425,IH,5561,07:00,0,07:00,1,1,1,1,1,0 




*C.ID                     Student ID, usually 7 digits (same as value from position 20-26)
*E.STAFF             Teacher staff ID, default to 999999 (same as value from position 1-6)
*E.DATE               Service Date, mm/dd/yyyy format (same as value from position 7-14 but different format)
*E.TIME               Time of service, hh:mm format (same as value from position 15-19; ie – 09:45, 14:15)
*E.SAC                  Service code, 4 digits (same as value from position 42-45)
*E.DESC               Description of service, IH or WD depending on type of file
*E.class                classroom #, 4 digits (same as value from position 27-30)
*E.DUR                 Event duration, hh:mm format (same as value from position 31-34 but in hour and minutes format; ie – 04:20)
*E.PREP               Preparation duration, hh:mm format, default to 0
*E.CL.DUR           Student duration, hh:mm format, same value as event duration
*E.ATT                  Attendance code, use 1 for present or 6 for absent (default to 1)
*E.RECIP              Recipient code, use 1 for with client or 9 for no recipient (default to 1)
*E.LOC                  Location code, use 1 for at center or 9 at other location (default to 1)
*E.PROJ               Project code, use 1 always (default to 1)
*E.NO.REC          Number of Recipients, use 1 or 0 (default to 1)
*E.FILLER             Filler, use 0 always (default to 0)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question on what exactly was not successful?

Comment: Based on what you describe your last step is to save the file as a csv file. HOWEVER, looking at the data I'm wondering if some transformation is being done. For example E.Desc says it should be IH or WD but the original data row doesn't show IH or WD in it.

Comment: There are a number of parameters which, if they are included in the original record, cannot be mapped to the individual properties from the information you provide.  Otherwise, the process can be accomplished with simple text formulas (and perhaps the `TEXT` function for some of the formatting.  The unmappable properties include `*E.DESC`, `*E.PREP`, and all the properties listed below `*E.PREP`

Answer (score 0):

Place your data in cell **A1** of *Sheet1* and downward.  Place the position *(field)* values in **B1** and **B2**, etc. like:

[image]

Then in *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=MID(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet1!B1,Sheet1!B2-Sheet1!B1+1)
```

copy this cell both across and downward.  Then save *Sheet2* in ***.csv*** format.